# React native not working in npm 5.3.0

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native. I installed it by:

```
npm install -g create-react-native-app
```

When I tried

```
create-react-native-app MyProject
```

it shows that npm 5 is not supported yet and I need to downgrade npm.
If I will downgrade npm, will it affect other projects?
Is there any other way without downgrade npm?

Comment: ```npm install -g npm@4``` ... takes you to version 4.6.1 currently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download and use [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install) instead of npm. If you change your npm version you have to use it with the other projects too. There are tools out there t let you use different versions of npm I think but I can't suggest anything because I never used them before.

I suggest you to use [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install).

Answer (score 4):

You can downgrade your version of npm with `npm install -g npm@4`
Then, you can run `create-react-native-app MyProject`